# Защита и проверка приложения

Tags: android

День добрый, у меня опять накопилось куча вопросов по разработке на `Android`.

1. Как лучше всего реализовать проверку что под одним аккаунтом сидит один человек а не 2, если 2ой заходит то у него выползает `alert` и дисконектится приложение
2. Как сделать проверку включен ли `GPS` и `Internet`. Если что-нибудь из пунктов выключено, перекидывать в настройки, если человек вернулся в приложение, перекидывать до того момента пока не включит GPS и `Internet`.

Готовое решение не требуется, если есть возможность, просто дайте за что зацепиться.
**PS.** Учусь писать под `Android`.

Comment: Вот это поворот приложений... Руки отрывать таким людям, которые будут постоянно в настройки отправлять.

Comment: Вы бы попробовали учиться на интересных и полезных вещах. Если вы, не умея ещё как следует писать программы, начинаете с разработки модуля наказания пользователей, вряд ли ваше приложение сможет завоевать большую популярность. Сначала придумайте то, что стоит защищать, а потом уж защищайте.

Comment: @VladD популярность у приложения быть и не должно, я не собираюсь на публику его выклаыдвать.

Comment: @pincher1519 Просто на будущее интересуюсь. Для себя же делаю)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.У устройства есть uuid, можно его использовать как идентификатор сессии работы с приложением.
 2.В приложении можно выставить разрешения на доступ к GPS и Internet функциям устройства. После этого в самом приложении можно обращаться к соответствующим API: [GPS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html), [NET](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 2):

В Андроид есть довольно подробно проработанный API защиты, называется [LVL - License Verification Library](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html) в принципе она довольно хорошо настраиваема. В дефолтном варианте она обеспечивает защиту от копирования по id юзера (GoogleId), но ничего не мешает ее усилить и привязкой к ID аппарата:

```
String deviceId=((TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getDeviceId();
```

Правда, `id` аппарата сбрасывается при wipe и некоторые аппараты возвращают ее значение всегда `null`